# Полулежа на животе

Tags: семантика

Возник спор из-за конструкции "полулежа на животе".
Имелось в виду, что человек лежит на животе, но с приподнятым туловищем, опираясь на локти, предплечья или даже кисти.

Вы можете представить себе эту позу?  Если да, насколько корректно будет само название?
Словари однозначного ответа не дают.

Answer (score 2):

> Вы можете представить себе эту позу?

Могу. Тоже, наверно, так же бы назвал. По-моему, вполне удачное выражение. Да, можно опираться на локти, ещё удобнее на предплечья, вот только если опираешься на кисти, кажется, что готовишься при этом к отжиманиям. :)

Попался пример на каком-то [сайте](https://www.medela.ru/breastfeeding/mums-journey/breastfeeding-positions) для мам:

> Кормить в позе «с нависанием» можно также сидя, стоя на коленях над малышом на кровати или диване, а также ***полулежа на животе*** с опорой на локти.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, я тоже не вижу в таком сочетании ничего противоестественного лингвистическолй точки зрения. А мне возражают, что традиционно "полулежа" означает то же, что и "полусидя" - те на сине, но с приподнятой верхней частью туловища.

Answer (score 1):

"Полулёжа" - самодостаточное выражение, которое подразумевает положение, среднее между "лёжа и сидя" (полулёжа-полусидя). Оно ассоциируется, как правило, с *расслабленной* боковой позой, что подтверждается напр. google images. "Полулёжа на животе" я воспринимаю как неологизм и гадаю, к чему отнести вторую "половину" (первое впечатление и попытка представить себе: "лёжа на половине живота"). "*Лёжа на животе, прогнувшись*" - есть такое положение в йоге и цигуне, требующее некоторого *напряжения*.

Comment: ну вот вы однозначно заняли сторону моих оппонентов. Я не про цигун, ессно, а про семантику вообще. Но меня ставит в тупик "расслабленная боковая поза". Это как? У фотографов есть "четверть-анфас" и подобные, но это совсем не лежачая поза.